# How to insert into array data?

Tags: php, laravel

I create scraper using Goutte library.I take posts from outside page. And now I insert into array post, witch has post_title, content and date keys. My problem is that this code works only for one post. I want to insert into array all posts. How can I do that ?

```
  $httpBrowser = new HttpBrowser();
$request = $httpBrowser->request('GET', $url);
$response = $request ->filter('.works');
        
        $arr = [];
        
        $arr['post_title'] = $response ->filter('.works__post')->text();
        $arr['content'] = $response ->filter('.works__content')->text();
        $arr['date'] = $response ->filter('.works__header-details--date')->text();
```

Comment: i think you should add the structure of the response to allow people to understand, however i believe there must be a for loop.

Comment: Please add the HTML structure of the page you're scraping.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `each` for you to loop through HTML elements. Perhaps something like this can work:

```php
$httpBrowser = new HttpBrowser();
$request = $httpBrowser->request('GET', $url);
$arr = [];

$response = $request->filter('.works')->each(function ($node) use (&$arr) {
    $item = [];
    $item['post_title'] = $node->filter('.works__post')->text();
    $item['content'] = $node->filter('.works__content')->text();
    $item['date'] = $node->filter('.works__header-details--date')->text();
    $arr[] = $item;
});
```